# PHP function with for each loop inside - what to return?

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, woocommerce, categories

I have navigation with product categories at top of website.

Want to repeat this navigation in footer of website.

Instead of writing $args, defining variables and such once again I decided to make a function for this.

It looks like this:

[image]

However as every function should have a return I'm confused how should return of this function look like?

When I try to return `<li>` instead of echoing it - I get nothing, empty area, but with echo - function works.

Comment: Not every function has a return, only if there is something which should be passed around.

Comment: And since no one said it: Don't post pictures of code! You make everyone else's lives more difficult when you do that. Post all code here directly as text!

Comment: This question is poor quality because the screenshot should be copy-pasted input text.  Please never post screenshots of textual data because this form of detail cannot be read by users with visual impairments not to mention that trouble that search engines will have with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of echo you can write `$return_data .= ...` to concatenate a string which was initially declared as an empty string before the loop began.

Here is a sample for such cases:

```
function show_prod_cats($all_categories) {
    $return_data = '';
    foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
        //echo '<li>....</li>';
        $return_data .= '<li>....</li>';
    }
    return $return_data;
}
```